# I want to make a function that will display only folders that contains images / mp3 / audio

Tags: android

What I want here is to display only the folders and subfolders that contains images or videos or mp3.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(fileList.get(i).getName());
        textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

        System.out.println(fileList.get(i).getName());

        if (fileList.get(i).isDirectory()) {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        view.addView(textView);
    }

}

public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {

    FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
            File sel = new File(dir, filename);
            // Filters based on whether the file is hidden or not
            return (((sel.isFile() || sel.isDirectory()) && !sel.isHidden()));


        //...

        }
    };

    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles(new ImageFileFilter());
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {

                fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                getfile(listFile[i]);

            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".png") || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".JPG") || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpeg") || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".gif") || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
                    //fileList.add(listFile[i].getParentFile());
                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

I tried the functions below but it still display the folders that doesn't include images or videos or mp3

```
private boolean isImageFile(String filePath) {
    if (filePath.endsWith("JPG") || filePath.endsWith("PNG") || filePath.endsWith(".mp3"))
    // Add other formats as desired
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private class ImageFileFilter implements FileFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {

            return true;
        } else if (isImageFile(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your accept function, you have the code              `return (((sel.isFile() || sel.isDirectory()) && !sel.isHidden()));`

Instead of returning true if sel.isDirectory, you'd need to search all files in that directory and look for media files in it, and return true only if one is found.  This would turn your algorithm into a recursive one which may have issues if you use symbolic links in your filesystem-  you'll have to beware of loops.  It may also cause performance issues.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to solve it without having issues while using recursive ?

Comment: You can work around the issue-  you'd have to get the cannonical path of the directory and not recurse into it if its an ancestor of the current directory.